# Can these ceiling beams be removed?

Tags: ceiling

Wanting to remove the center posts that are coming down on the diagonal from these beams, is that possible? We then plan to clad them to make them more pleasing to the eye.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a chance that all of those beams are decorative.  That doesn't look like lumber I would use to bear any weight.

Comment: You should take this query to a structural engineer who will inspect, and more importantly will carry the risk if they're wrong.  A bunch of people on the web looking at photos don't have the same authority.

Answer (score 1):

No, that center post is in compression and is sharing the load as part of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is old they could very well be structural with a bit of design flair, if it's a newer house I'd say they are just design flair. Either way without more information your best bet is, as the comments suggest, have someone have a look at it.